# Parse.com: with parseUser, how can I save data in a column I created in parse from the class?

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, parse-platform

I am using Android Studio for my app and Parse for my database... and on the create an account page I have, it allows the user to enter in first name, last name, email, username, and password.

But my code is using parseUser... I don't know how to set the first and last name in the database. 
I know setUsername, setPassword, setEmail is a part of it... but what about if you make a column in Parse? How can you add this in your class?

This is a part of my code, what it looks like...my problem is in the else statement I have:

```
          // Force user to fill up the form
            if (usernametxt.equals("") && passwordtxt.equals("") && emailtxt.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please fill in the username, password, and email fields.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                // Save new user data into Parse.com Data Storage
                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();

                //somehow save first and last name 

                user.setEmail(emailtxt);
                user.setUsername(usernametxt);
                user.setPassword(passwordtxt);
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, Parse does provide methods to save username, passwords like **setUsername(params)** and **setPassword(params)** but if you want to add more data to the tables, you can create more columns according to your needs as I did in this code snippet.

If you have come columns created already in parse back-end like name, phone,address,cityState,companyId, this is how I am doing it.

```
private void savetoParse() {

        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
        user.setUsername(usernameEditText.getText().toString());
        user.setPassword(passEditText.getText().toString());
        user.put("name", nameEditText.getText().toString());
        user.setEmail(emailEditText.getText().toString());
        user.put("phone", phoneNoEditText.getText().toString());
        user.put("address", addressEditText.getText().toString());
        user.put("cityState", cityStateEditText.getText().toString());
        user.put("companyID", compSchoolIdEditText.getText().toString());

        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {

                if (e != null) {

                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivityUpdate.this,
                            "Saving user failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w(TAG,
                            "Error : " + e.getMessage() + ":::" + e.getCode());

                    if (e.getCode() == 202) {

                        Toast.makeText(
                                SignupActivityUpdate.this,
                                "Username already taken. \n Please choose another username.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        usernameEditText.setText("");
                        passEditText.setText("");
                        confirmPassEditText.setText("");

                    }

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivityUpdate.this, "User Saved",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    /*Do some things here if you want to.*/

                }

            }
        });
```

**NOTE :** The first params is the column name and second is the value. So, it basically acts like a key value pair.

This is solve the problem..lemme know if this works..good luck..:)

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped, I followed along with how you did this and I was able to save the new columns!

Comment: That's awesome!!. I am glad I was able to help .. :)

Comment: hi can we change the default table(user) to any other  table?

Comment: Of course u can.. u can always create your own table name or any other entities in parse.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * user Registration here
     * save user registration value on server here
     */
    private void userRegistration()
    {
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(SignUpThirdPage.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait......");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();


        user.setUsername("Name");   
        user.setPassword(strPassword);
        user.setEmail(strEmailId);
        // surName column create on parse.com db you can check after run that code
        // like that u can add more column in signup table
         user.put("surName","Kumar");

        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (e == null) {


                    }

                } else {
                    // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                    // to figure out what went wrong
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if(e.getMessage().contains("already taken")){
                        alertDialog("", "you've already sign up , lets login in ", SignUpThirdPage.this, false);    
                    }
                    else if(e.getMessage().contains("has already been taken")){
                        alertDialog("", "you've already sign up , lets login in ", SignUpThirdPage.this, false);    
                    }
                    else {
                        AppConstants.showAlertDialog("", e.getMessage(), SignUpThirdPage.this, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Rohitashvjain  i have table "table1"  in parse now how to  save data in that table from android ?