# Parse.com - create fields in User table from code

Tags: android, parse-platform

Normally with Parse code I can add whatever fields I want using `put`, and if they don't exist in the table (and the table permissions allow it) parse will create the field(s).  However, this doesn't work with the User table.  If I add the fields from the web interface everything works, but if not the code will not create the fields.  Is this a limitation particular to the User table, or am I missing something?  The permissions allow client creation of fields.  Following is Android code.

```
currentUser.setEmail(uname);
currentUser.setUsername(uname);
currentUser.put("phoneNumber", settings.getAgentPhone());
currentUser.put("company", settings.getAgentCompanyName());
currentUser.put("agentName", settings.getAgentName());
currentUser.saveEventually();
```

Comment: try to use currentUser.saveInBackground();

Comment: I'm not certain, but I don't think that would have any different outcome.  Adding the fields at signup works though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Parse.com: with parseUser, how can I save data in a column I created in parse from the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435079/parse-com-with-parseuser-how-can-i-save-data-in-a-column-i-created-in-parse-fr)

For some reason, you cannot add columns to the User table with a save operation from client code, but you can via the "signup" operations (`signUp`,`signUpInBackground`).  I have not found any reference to this in the parse documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the User class has some sort of "special restrictions". Have you tried using the master key in Cloud Code?

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

Using the master key would essentially allow you to bypass most, if not all, restrictions (essentially gives you administrative permissions)

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. This project doesn't involve any cloud code so I will have to decide if it would be easier to do by using cloud code or just manually adding the fields.  Unfortunately there are many apps to update or I would have just done it already.

Comment: Ya...the user class always gives me the trouble. Cloud code would technically involve more code but it would probably get the job done :)

Comment: @nasch hey, just want to know if you figured out your problem yet? :)

Comment: I decided to just do it by hand since it's a one-time thing.